# The specified field could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of my SQL statement

Tags: mysql

The specified field is `MatchID`. Cant figure out how to fix it. I have tried adding `tblPlayerStatistics` to `MatchID` after `GROUP BY` and that hasn't worked.

```
SELECT tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number, 
SUM(tblPlayerStatistics.TwoPointerMade + tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade)
AS points, MatchID
FROM tblPlayerStatistics INNER JOIN tblGameResults 
     ON tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID
GROUP BY tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number,MatchID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number, 
SUM(tblPlayerStatistics.TwoPointerMade + tblPlayerStatistics.ThreePointerMade) AS points,    
tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID 
FROM tblPlayerStatistics 
INNER JOIN tblGameResults ON tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID 
GROUP BY tblPlayerStatistics.Player_ID_Number, tblPlayerStatistics.MatchID;
```

You need to specify the table in which MatchID belongs to in your GROUP BY

Comment: I tried that at first and it still has the same error unfortunatley

Comment: There was another reference to MatchID that didn't have a table specified, I've altered my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this problem with the `using` clause:

```
SELECT ps.Player_ID_Number, 
       SUM(ps.TwoPointerMade + ps.ThreePointerMade) AS points, 
       MatchID
FROM tblPlayerStatistics ps INNER JOIN
     tblGameResults gr
     USING (MatchId)
GROUP BY ps.Player_ID_Number, MatchID;
```

I also introduced table aliases (abbreviations) to make the query more readable.

Comment: that is something I am not so familiar with but I have tried it and a syntax error in FROM clause appears

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this

```
SELECT tps.Player_ID_Number, 
SUM(tps.TwoPointerMade + tps.ThreePointerMade) AS points,
tps.MatchID                        <-- Here refer the table where MatchID taken
FROM tblPlayerStatistics tps INNER JOIN tblGameResults tgr
     ON tps.MatchID = tgr.MatchID
GROUP BY tps.Player_ID_Number,tps.MatchID;  <--So does Here
```